# VNC or NX from Mac client to Linux server

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, nomachine-nx

I run an NX server and tightvncserver on my linux box (Ubuntu 10.04), with default settings.
I have NX client and Chicken of VNC on my Mac (Snow Leopard).

I'd like to share desktop of the linux server with my Mac client, i.e., control the existing Linux user session from Mac.

But it seems that on my Mac both NX and VNC connections start a new session on the server.
I'd love to know how to do a "desktop sharing" instead of standalone remote session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [winswitch](http://winswitch.org/about/) - it will give you a GUI where you can start/stop sessions, the X11 display of your Linux machine will be shown as an existing session which you can "shadow"/"copy" via NX or VNC. (there are installers for macs and windows too)

If you want to do this by hand you can use `x0vncserver` for VNC and `nxagent -S` for NX, but then you will also have to deal with port configuration and IP/hostname addressing.. (as well as configuring nx DISPLAY environment variable which is totally non trivial)

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. After installing WinSwitch, I chose to use VNC as the backend for shadowing because I wasn't sure how straightforward the FreeNX configuration would be. Seemed that there were complaints about compatibility issues when there are mismatching NX component versions.. (my NX was the official one which doesn't come with nxagent, required as WinSwitch shadowing's NX backend). But the VNC route works pretty well.

Comment: Don't worry about NX: winswitch does not use FreeNX or nomachine's NX server so there is not risk that they will interfere, it only uses the NX libraries and those are backwards compatible (at least for the 3.x series which has been going for many years). If my original answer satisfies you, please consider accepting it.

Comment: Thanks totaam, I just accepted it. I'm new here and didn't know that I don't need reputation to make that "check", lol.